# read chars from file to array vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, file, char, multidimensional-array

The file I need to read in is a square 8x8 or NxN. the chars are separated by spaces and at the end of the line I believe a crlf. When I try to read in the file i get the crlf's when i use this code:

```
Dim stream As New FileStream(fileNAME, FileMode.Open)
Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)
```

`Dim temparray() As String = reader.ReadToEnd.Split(" ")`

I get stuff like this `temparray(7) "K  B"`

what I need to do after that is put into a 2d array of 8x8 or NxN sample file is 8x8

or if there is a way to get it into a 2d array with out using a 1d array first that would be great.

sample file:

A B R A E L R K

B R E D A A O L

C A R R O T D I

H P N L K M I L

E P G A P P L E

E E O M N O K F

S L S R G A S A

E I F I S E H A

Comment: Do you know how many rows there are in advance? (I guess it doesn't matter too much, since you can always calculate the number of rows from the file size...)

Comment: By the way, the `File.ReadAllText()` function might make things a bit easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) can take an array of chars that you want to split on, so you can handle space, and new lines in one go.

Try:

```
Dim temparray() As String = reader.ReadToEnd.Split(New Char() {" "c, vbCr, vbCrLf})
```

In fact, it appears if you pass null/Nothing for the separater, Split will default to any whitespace characters. So this should work as well:

```
Dim temparray() As String = reader.ReadToEnd.Split(Nothing)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. the first one worked. the second one still added the crlf's

Comment: i just noticed that at the front of every line there is a space with the letter it returns  temparray(8)= " B" except for he first line.